# Adding document to Sharepoint 2010 document list using List service

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I am looking for an example in C#.net how to add document/file to sharepoint document list using its List service but didn't found any satisfactory example?

looking for an example to which I can refer.

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the List service for that. You will need to use the Copy webservice. [Here is an example](http://nikspatel.wordpress.com/2010/04/12/download-and-upload-the-sharepoint-documents-using-the-sharepoint-copy-web-service/).